# Enzyme call method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

Let's say I have a method in my React component:

```
doSomething() {
    // method uses this.props and this.state
}
```

I want to test this method for different props and states that are set. So how can I call it? `MyClass.prototype.doSomething` will call the function, but then `this.props` and `this.state` are not set.

Comment: so when you create the component with enzyme, what's stopping you from just passing in the props?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

**NOTE: [@Tyler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44832930/2518231) below is the better solution**

You could just [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) the value of `this` that you want to use:

```
// MyClass.prototype.doSomething() becomes

var mockThis = { 
  props: { coolProp: 'coolValue1' }, 
  state: { coolStateKey: 'coolValue2' }
};
MyClass.prototype.doSomething.apply(mockThis);`
```

Comment: This is not a really appropriate solution. `MyClass` is now forever dirtied; future calls to it will have the mock set.

Comment: @Kousha not of OP is properly setting his tests cases up. Ex: creating a new instance of `MyClass` in the `beforeEach` block of Jasmine tests.

Answer (score 33):

You can use enzyme's `instance` function to get an instance of the rendered component, and call methods on it.

`const wrapper = shallow(<MyClass {...props} />)
wrapper.instance().doSomething()`

Comment: Yes this works. Just bear in mind that when you check the state afterwards, you should check `wrapper`, not `wrapper.instance()`.

Answer (score -1):

Let's proceed under the assumption your doSomething() method is increaseByOne() which just adds +1

```
describe('Calculator', () => {
  it('should update state by 1 on increaseByOne()', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Calculator />);
    expect(wrapper.instance().state().score).toBe(0);
    wrapper.instance().increaseByOne();
    expect(wrapper.instance().state().score).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

To find out more you can check out the documentation about [state()](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/state.html) and [Instance() docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html)